# Increment a constant with pandas time series data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have pandas time-series data frame at 1 min resolution for 2 days (as shown in the attached image) and a constant (say 30). I want to write a code to increment the constant with the time-series value of `Output_Energy` (a column in df) every minute till the constant has a value, (say 80).

I think it can be done using a while loop but being a beginner facing some issues. I really appreciate your help.

data (It's not possible to copy/paste whole data):

```
                           Duty_cycle Output_Current Output_Power Output_Energy
2016-06-20 05:26:00+05:30   0.585620    0.000181    0.009889    1.648155e-07
2016-06-20 05:27:00+05:30   0.525725    0.000661    0.036118    6.019588e-07
2016-06-20 05:28:00+05:30   0.491520    0.001582    0.086358    1.439302e-06
2016-06-20 05:29:00+05:30   0.467207    0.003167    0.172917    2.881952e-06
2016-06-20 05:30:00+05:30   0.448211    0.005702    0.311310    5.188504e-06
2016-06-20 05:31:00+05:30   0.432784    0.009523    0.519970    8.666170e-06
2016-06-20 05:32:00+05:30   0.419933    0.015013    0.819685    1.366141e-05
2016-06-20 05:33:00+05:30   0.408929    0.022579    1.232801    2.054668e-05
2016-06-20 05:34:00+05:30   0.399607    0.032643    1.782283    2.970472e-05
2016-06-20 05:35:00+05:30   0.391331    0.045618    2.490732    4.151220e-05
```

[image: pandas data frame]

Comment: Please provide your dataset as *text* that can be copy/pasted to form a dataframe

Comment: @mozway It's not possible to copy/paste the whole data but I hope few rows will help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
num = 30
ind = 0
while True:
    sum = num + df.iloc[ind, 3]
    if sum > 80:
        break

    num = sum
    ind += 1
```

...?

**EDIT**
Regarding comment Nikhil's comment.

`ind` is just an index, so that you can step through each row in the dataframe in sequence. There is likely another way to do it exclusively using `pandas` functions, but this is a general strategy that is language and framework independent.

`ind` is not an iterator.

The change you need with `num2` is simple enough with an `if`, `elif`, `else` statement:

```
num = 30
num2 = 40
ind = 0
while True:
    
    if num < 80:
        num += df.iloc[ind, 3]
    elif <some condition>:
        num2 += df.iloc[ind, 3]
    else:
        break

    ind += 1
```

But keep in mind that you'd need to stipulate some condition whereby the function should terminate.

One more thing to consider is that there is no bound checking in this code, so you could run out of entries before you reach 80 or whatever sentinel value you choose. Thus, it'd be good to include something along the lines of:

```
if ind == df.shape[0]:
    break
elif sum > 80:
...
```

just to make sure you don't get an out of bounds error.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you. Could you please briefly explain the use of `ind` ? Is it an iterator? Secondly, is it possible to have time-series output? I want to plot it w.r.t. time for analysis. Last but not least if I assume another constant say `num2 =40` and want to start adding the data to this one from the point loop for `num` break. What changes/ addition we need to make in the above code?

Comment: Thanks for the edit!
I think I couldn't convey properly what I meant with the last question in my comment. Let's suppose `num` reaches `80` at `ind=400`. What I am trying to do after that is to start adding the data to `num2` from `ind=401` until it reaches the value `80`. Does the EDITted code will do the work?

Comment: @Nikhil just replace ```<some condition>``` with ```num2 < 80``` and Bob's your uncle.